# Does signal strength affect download/upload speeds?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm using a 3G USB stick to connect to the internet, depending on my location the signal strength varies.

So my question is, does signal strength affect throughput and why?

Comment: I would like to see some quantitative measure of db level versus speed.  if you get a weak signal, but still get high throughput, then it's not such an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no... (depending on both stick and service)

If you are talking about the difference between five and four bars, you are not very likely to see a difference, however if talking about one and two, it can make a big difference.

The only way to really tell is to use a speed checker or the utility that comes with the 3G card and tell.

Typically on the newer faster sticks (7.2MB) quality can make a big difference. On some of the slower ones (~2MB) I do not see much of a difference from 2-5 bars. Again, it depends on many other factors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  A weaker signal will result in a lower bandwidth connection, thus negatively affecting throughput.